# how to get the id of a dynamic list items

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a dynamic list of items which I want to display the details whenever a particular item is clicked.

**HTML**

```
<a id="item1" class="list-item"/>
<a id="item2" class="list-item"/>
```

**JS**

```
$('#list-item').click(function () {
       //how do I obtain the id of the specific item?
});
```

So the question is how do I get the ID of the list item and do I need to declare a onclick behavior at the item's html code?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.list-item').click(function () {
   aler($(this).prop('id'));
});
```

Comment: so I have to do something like
    var id = $(this).attr('id')?

Comment: @AvanCaiJun or like the answer suggested by Arun `alert(this.id)`

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things you have to do

1. Use a class selector to select the elements are `list-item` is a class not id
2. `this` inside the click handler will refer the clicked `anchor` element so you can get its `id` property to get the id

```js
//use class selector

$('.list-item').click(function() {
  //Here this refers to the clicked element so
  alert(this.id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="item1" class="list-item">1<a/>
<a id="item2" class="list-item">2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.list-item').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    // Do things with the ID here.
});
```

As noted by Arun, in your example `list-item` is a class and not an id.  Therefore you have to use `.list-item` as a selector instead of `#list-item`.

Answer (score 0):

list-item is a class, not an Id  so use class selector:

```
$('li.list-item').click (finction (){
  $(this).attr ('id');//gets the I'd
});
```